# Convert String to DateTime Format

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

I am getting a date and time from a data feed which I cannot change, and I need to convert it to a `DateTime`.

The format of the string is as follows.

```
timestamp="20131204T171054+0000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to resort to using sub strings here is my code:

```
Dim Date As Date = datestamp.Substring(6, 2) & "/" & datestamp.Substring(4, 2) & "/" & datestamp.Substring(0, 4) & " " &
                            timestamp.Substring(0, 2) & ":" & timestamp.Substring(2, 2) & ":" & timestamp.Substring(4, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify a [Custom Date and Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your sample looks like "yyyyMMddTHHmmssK" might work.

In vb.net

```
Dim timestamp As String = "20131204T171054+0000"
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

In C#

```
string timestamp = "20131204T171054+0000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd take Haji's approach if you are dealing with a well defined environment. Global time handling is a bear.

I'd split the string to a valid date and time:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = "2013.12.04 17:10:54"
```

then adjust for the offset.

Answer (score -1):

use the `DateTime.Parse` Function. You must pass a string value as its argument. Then, you can assign a DateTime to its result. This transforms the string into a value indicating the DateTime.  below is the example of converting the sample string to datatime. I don't have any idea about the string you given in the question..

```
  Dim value As String = "2000-02-02"
  Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(value)
```

Comment: What that has to do with specific datetime format mentioned by OP?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter sorry my mistake. as per the question header i given some string for sample conversion.